# Kuberbetes: Kompose up error while deploying application

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kompose

I am attempting to run compose up and am running the following command `sudo kompose up --push-image=false --verbose` kompose builds all the containers successfully but right at the very end throws this error:

```
FATA Error while deploying application: Get https://127.0.0.1:6443/api: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connection refused
```

I have even run `kubectl proxy` but this didn't fix the problem, can anyone please help?

EDIT: To clarify I am using minikube, it is running in the background but Kompose still doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please reserve a time to read the  [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page and also visit theses links to know [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)  and [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including warnings, errors, and details to reproduce your scenario will allow everyone here to help you with your question. Are you using minikube? Please share more information about your setup.

Comment: yes I am using minikube, I cannot share my config as it is for work purposes but i am using the defaults of everything in Kubernetes and the standard docker configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue ended up being the fact that the certificates for the kubectl proxy commanded were not self signed by default, I got around this using `kompose up --server http://127.0.0.1:6443` but I cannot use the Kubernetes Dashboard without the certificates.